# Continuous terminal output to a file

Tags: command-line, log

I am running a software which keeps on printing the steps followed and progress of it on the terminal. I would like to redirect the output from terminal to log file as and when the software prints something on the terminal. I don't want to wait until the software terminates.

All the commands seems to help after the program terminates to log the output to a file.

The output should be **only** in log file not on **STDOUT(terminal)**

Answer (score 1):

You only need to redirect that command output to a file like:

```
your_command > outfile
```

You can add `&` in the end in above command to send the command to running in background if you needed.

```
your_command > outfile &
```